# Laravel 8 in centos 8 Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, centos

I have an installation of a LaraVel system running properly under a subdirectory installed in WordPress on a CentOS 8 server, this subdirectory works correctly, but install a new subdirectory with a new installation of Laravel 8, in which I receive Error: You Don ' t have permission to access / subdirectory / on this server.

Try copying the .htaccess from the subdirectory in Laravel that is working, and did not give positive results, I have also tried other htaccess that I have found by the web and in Stackoverflow but nothing works.

The htaccess that works in the other subdirectory is the following:

```
<Ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
<IFModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -Multiviews -indexes.
</ Ifmodule>

RewriteEngine On.

# Handle Authorization Header
Rewritecond% {http: authorization}.
Rewriterule * - [E = HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:% {http: Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If not Folder ...
Rewritecond% {request_FileName}!
Rewritecond% {request_uri} (. +) / $
Rewriterule ^% 1 [L, R = 301]

# Handle Front Controller ...
Rewritecond% {request_FileName}!
Rewritecond% {request_FileName}! -F
Rewriterule ^ index.php [L]
</ Ifmodule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your htaccess rule file in following way, please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<Ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
<IFModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -Multiviews -indexes
</Ifmodule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{http: authorization}
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If not Folder ...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Handle Front Controller ...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewriterule ^ index.php [L]
</Ifmodule>
```